# Jenkins xcode plugin - how to resolve library search path issues?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, restkit, continuous-deployment

I am running into this error in my jenkins xcode build which I'm attempting to setup:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/boo/.jenkins/jobs/myProject/workspace/DerivedData/Release-iphoneos/libIBAForms.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/boo/.jenkins/jobs/myProject/workspace/DerivedData/Release-iphoneos/libLambdaAlert.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/boo/.jenkins/jobs/myProject/workspace/DerivedData/Release-iphoneos/libRestKit.a'
```

I cannot figure out a few things regarding the configuration:

1. what prompted the jenkins-xcode-plugin ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin ) to use `/DerivedData/Release-iphoneos/` in the path for the lookup of the .a files
2. instead why didn't it select `/DerivedData/Debug-iphoneos/` as the fragment in the path for the lookup to the .a files
3. finally the submodules that produce - libIBAForms, libLambdaAlert, libRestKit - are all projects that have a `release` and a `debug` profile ... so why the files are actually missing from the `/DerivedData/Release-iphoneos/` path where they are supposed to be ... is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past all this when I adeed the submodules which generate libIBAForms and libLambdaAlert as the main project's "Target Dependencies"

Answer (score 1):

Regarding points #1 and #2, this is configured based on the **Configuration** parameter for XCode plugin (and Xcode itself). By default, the plugin uses "Release" value for the parameter. If you want to use "Debug", you should set it as such.

Don't know what to say regarding #3

Personally, i found the Xcode plugin to be restrictive and not providing me with options that i needed. I am using the command line tools that came with xcode (through regular **Execute Shell** build step)

```
// Below are my build parameters for the job through regular means
CONFIGURATION=Debug
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: <DeveloperNameHere>
PROVISIONING_PROFILE=3000000B-7000-4000-9CD5-D0000B0F0000
//

// Code for Execute Shell
xcodebuild -verbose -alltargets -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}
&&
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${WORKSPACE}/path_here/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/application.app" -o "${WORKSPACE}/path_here/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/application.ipa" --sign "${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" --embed "/Users/<youruser>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}.mobileprovision"
```

Setup parameters as usual for the job
The xcodebuild command does the actual build
The xcrun command packages the app into an IPA (the Archive step in Xcode), signs it, and embeds a provisioning profile directly into the IPA.

Note that some of these switches are options and may not be required for you. But that's the benefit of doing through the command line: you have full control of what you want to do

Small note: make sure you provide full paths to `-v` and `-o` switches on the second command

Comment: The provisioning profile for AdHoc does not equal 'build configuration'. However you may have a build configuration created called 'AdHoc' (i wouldn't know, it's your project). In either case, specify the Build Configuration and the provisioning profiles that you want.

Comment: I've had to move on to other work for a few months and no one else on my team is available to verify your solution Slav. Would you like me to mark your solution as the "answer" ... given all the work you put into it? Or are you ok with me coming back to this in a few months and really digging in?

Comment: Heh, it's fine with me whatever you do :)